# Running ParseySaurus

Tags: python, tensorflow, parsey-mcparseface

I've been hacking around with Parsey McParseface and Parsey Universal. Google released their next version of the parser:

https://research.googleblog.com/2017/03/an-upgrade-to-syntaxnet-new-models-and.html

After a bit of looking I was able to find and download the models, but I can't seem to find a way to actually run them i.e.

echo "I have it working" | syntaxnet/models/parsey_saurus_english/parse.sh

There is no parse.sh and using the demo.sh or parsey_universals parse.sh also won't work.

Has anyone gotten them working or found a tutorial somewhere that I could get started with?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code did you download? I can't find a Git repository with a directory called `parsey_saurus_english`, and it doesn't seem to be part of the standard SyntaxNet repo.

Comment: @mrry ParseySaurus was released on the google blog here: 
https://research.googleblog.com/2017/03/an-upgrade-to-syntaxnet-new-models-and.html
 The models can be downloaded from the link here 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/syntaxnet/g3doc/conll2017

Answer (score 0):

There has been a stall in the issue [#2822](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2822) on github which makes it problematic to build syntaxnet with bazel. Instead I have modified the syntaxnet docker file and use that in my project. [Here](https://github.com/shubham0704/syntaxnet-minimal) is a link to the repo.
Hope it helps :)